# How do i disable horizontal scrolling? (Not removal of the horizontal scrollbar)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Im making a website, and im designing it in a special way with a very wide div (absolute position) that got all the content of every menu-button in it.

Some of thease divs got more content than others, so there's a vertical scrollbar - (and im fine with that) - and i disabled the horizontal one, BUT! As the technology spins forward some evil company have invented the horizontal scroll-function for computer mice, and smartphone users can swipe sideways at it.

This mousefunction doesnt really destroy my design-idea, but it would be incredibly awesome if the ability to scroll horizontally with any button/mouse/etc could be disabled. Can that be done with CSS/Javascript/HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best answer is to change your approach.
Browsers 'could' allow this kind of thing - and mayhem would ensue - which is the reason they don't.

Redesign your layout with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a strange website, and without seeing it, people may have difficulty with their recommendations.

It seems like the proper way of fixing it would be to ensure that nothing goes off the edge of the screen.  If you don't want something visible, hide it (with, for example, `display: none`) - rather than trying to put it off the edge of the screen.

Anything else, I imagine, would be a nasty hack.  You *could* try to effectively disable scrolling by watching for "scroll" events and resetting the scroll position each time, but it'd be the wrong way to go about it.

If there is something off-screen to the right or bottom, browsers will want to let people scroll to it.

But again, without seeing the site, I'm feeling around in the dark here.  I don't know what issues you're solving.